# The different 'on commit' setting with Oracle Global Temp Table

Tags: oracle, performance, global-temp-tables

Would any one please advise on the mechanism behind the two different settings for the Oracle GTT?

1) on commit preserve rows

2) on commit delete rows

For now I know there 'facts':

a) the records inserted into these 2 types of GTT have different lifecycle.

b) the definition of both types of GTT remains until we drop the GTT <[REF](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB6964-How-to-enable-true-temporary-tables-in-Oracle-in)>.

However, what I would like to know i whether there is any difference between the 2 types of GTT in terms of the fact b)?

I was told that, for the 'preserve' type of GTT, the table's definition will not only remain but will accumulate by the times of usage (i.e. if there are 10 sessions using the GTT, 10 copies of the table's definition will be created and won't be disappear until we drop the GTT). And if we don't drop the 'preserve' GTT on a regular basis, the SQL statement's performance will become slower and slower.

Please could anyone demystify?

【2018.08.21】
Thanks all for answering the question. Please allow me to refine the question, it is not the table definition of the GTT is being duplicated, but the tablespace being allocated by every sessions using the same GTT that wont be released by the end of session but a dedicated drop of the GTT. Would that be the truth?

Comment: Who told you that? There is only one table definition, however many session have data in it. And all of that data will disappear as the sessions end, or if they explicitly delete their data of course.

Comment: "When you create a temporary table it will not use any tablespace. It will use the TEMPORARY tablespace of the current schema when accessed at runtime. When you create a temp table -- no space allocated. when you insert into temp table, the space will be gotten from your temporary tablespace (or if the temporary table is used in a stored procedure with definer rights - the temporary tablespace of the owner of the table)"

Take a look at https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=about-temporary-tables

Comment: You were lied to.

Comment: `...the tablespace being allocated by every sessions using the same GTT that wont be released by the end of session but a dedicated drop of the GTT` - I think you have misunderstood how a GTT works. I suggest you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1138), which specifically states: `Temporary segments are deallocated at the end of the transaction for transaction-specific temporary tables and at the end of the session for session-specific temporary tables.` Hopefully that answers your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can check the temporary segments associated with the GTTs in `v$tempseg_usage`:

```
create global temporary table demo_gtt_preserve (id int) on commit preserve rows;
create global temporary table demo_gtt_delete (id int) on commit delete rows;

insert into demo_gtt_preserve values (1);
insert into demo_gtt_delete values (1);

select s.sql_text, tu.tablespace, tu.contents, tu.segtype, tu.segfile#, tu.segblk#
from   v$tempseg_usage tu
       join v$sql s on s.sql_id = tu.sql_id_tempseg
where  tu.username = user
and    tu.segtype = 'DATA'
and    tu.session_num = dbms_debug_jdwp.current_session_serial;
```

Result:

```
SQL_TEXT                                 TABLESPACE CONTENTS  SEGTYP SEGFILE#    SEGBLK#
---------------------------------------- ---------- --------- ------ -------- ----------
insert into demo_gtt_delete values (1)   TEMP       TEMPORARY DATA        401     438528
insert into demo_gtt_preserve values (1) TEMP       TEMPORARY DATA        401     438400
```

Now if you commit and rerun the query, you only get one row:

```
SQL_TEXT                                 TABLESPACE CONTENTS  SEGTYPE SEGFILE#   SEGBLK#
---------------------------------------- ---------- --------- ------- -------- ---------
insert into demo_gtt_preserve values (1) TEMP       TEMPORARY DATA         401    438400
```

(Somewhat unhelpfully, `v$tempseg_usage` identifies the session by `session_addr` and `session_num`, which correspond to `saddr` and `serial#` in `v$session`, neither of which are exposed via `sys_context`. You could extend the query above by joining to `v$session` and filtering on `sid = sys_context('userenv','sid')` or `audsid = sys_context('userenv','sessionid')` if you want to limit it to your own session.)

The only way to clear the remaining entry is to disconnect the session, or drop or truncate the table.

Regarding the performance question, note the way this works: when your session uses a GTT, a completely new temporary segment is created just for you. If other sessions do the same thing, they each get their own separate temporary segments. As those sessions commit or disconnect, the corresponding temporary segments are dropped. There is nothing shared between sessions, because each session has its own separate instance of the temporary table. Therefore, the rumour that *if we don't drop the 'preserve' GTT on a regular basis, the SQL statement's performance will become slower and slower* doesn't make sense.